# how to take image from iphone phonebook using programming?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

there are two normal ways to import images (from camera and from album) but I also want to take images of iphone phonebook, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below can be used for getting image from AddressBook

```
NSData  *imgData = (NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);

UIImage  *img = [UIImage imgaeWithData:imgData];
```

where person is of type `ABRecordRef`. Now as `CFData` and `NSData` are

**toll-free bridged**

, so you can simply type cast `CFData` to `NSData` and get the image

Here is the Tutorial

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/02/get-image-from-contact-stored-in-addressbook/

Answer (score 0):

If with "phonebook" you mean AddressBook framework to access contacts data, try using [Erica Sadun](http://ericasadun.com)'s [AB cocoa wrapper](https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper). It includes a sample project, so it will be easy.